# How do I solve tensor mismatch if I want to use F1 score as a metric in pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

I am attempting to build a convulational neural network from scratch for object recognition. My input image size is (3, 256, 256)

Here's my architecture for CNN.

```
class NutSnackClassication(MultiLabelImageClassificationBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.network = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2,2),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2,2),
            
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1), 
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
            
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(7*7*256, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 258),
            nn.LogSoftmax(dim = 1),
        )
    
    def forward(self, xb):
        return self.network(xb)
```

I have to use Weighted accuracy of all classes so I chose to use F1 Score as metric to evaluate my models performance.

```
def F_score(output, label, threshold=0.5, beta=1):
    prob = output > threshold
    label = label > threshold
    print(prob.shape, "---", label.shape)
    TP = (prob & label).sum(1).float()
    TN = ((~prob) & (~label)).sum(1).float()
    FP = (prob & (~label)).sum(1).float()
    FN = ((~prob) & label).sum(1).float()

    precision = torch.mean(TP / (TP + FP + 1e-12))
    recall = torch.mean(TP / (TP + FN + 1e-12))
    F2 = (1 + beta**2) * precision * recall / (beta**2 * precision + recall + 1e-12)
    return F2.mean(0)
```

Specifically I am using this function below:

```
    # validation step
    def validation_step(self, batch):
        images, targets = batch
        out = self(images)
        loss = F.nll_loss(out, targets)
        score = F_score(out, targets)
        return {'val_loss': loss.detach(), 'val_score': score.detach() }
```

But when I execute this `evaluate(model, val_dl)`  I get an error saying:

```
torch.Size([128, 258]) --- torch.Size([128])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)


RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (258) must match the size of tensor b (128) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

I dont understand how to solve this. Is my `F1_Score()` rightly implemented? How do I approach a solution to this?

After making changes as suggested be the answer I get this error:

```
---> 12     TP = (prob & label).sum(1).float()
     13     TN = ((~prob) & (~label)).sum(1).float()
     14     FP = (prob & (~label)).sum(1).float()

IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

Following is the change I made:

```
def F_score(output, label, threshold=0.5, beta=1):
    _, prob = torch.max(output, dim = 1)
    # print(_.shape, "---", prob.shape)
    prob = prob
    label = label > threshold
    
    TP = (prob & label).sum(1).float()
    TN = ((~prob) & (~label)).sum(1).float()
    FP = (prob & (~label)).sum(1).float()
    FN = ((~prob) & label).sum(1).float()

    precision = torch.mean(TP / (TP + FP + 1e-12))
    recall = torch.mean(TP / (TP + FN + 1e-12))
    F2 = (1 + beta**2) * precision * recall / (beta**2 * precision + recall + 1e-12)
    return F2.mean(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is `nn.Linear(512, 258)`, I assumed batch output has 128 images with 256 classes, so `shape=(128,256)`. But labels only a list for 128 images, so `shape=(128)`.

You need `labels` and `outputs` to have the same dimension. You can use `torch.max` to find the class for each image with the highest score (note that I assumed your class's labels are integer with 256 classes), and it will return the same size as your labels.

`torch.max` will return `tuple(values, index)` where values are the list of maximum values in the dimension you want, and the index will return a list of the index of the maximum values.

```
def F_score(output, label, threshold=0.5, beta=1):
    _, prob = torch.max(output, dim = 1) #Find class with highest score from output
    prob = prob > threshold   #Also change this line
    label = label > threshold
    print(prob.shape, "---", label.shape)
    ...
```

Comment: There are 258 classes and I am still geting the same error when I include ``` torch.max() ``` line.

Comment: Did you change `prob = prob > threshold` line?

Comment: Sorry I dont know what to change if with?

Comment: So I made following changes: I removed the line  prob > threshold and replaced it with _, prob = torch.max(output, dim = 1)  but I am still getting the same error. So what should I change?

Comment: Change the line I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Hey can you check the post again? I added the results.

Comment: I'm not sure your code is right because when calculation the f1 score we need `TP, TN, FP, FN` for each class. I suggest using Scikit-learn for your problem. If you want to use the same code change `sum(1).float()` to `sum().float` but the values are wrong.